# I can't run configure script in windows command prompt

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I have to download a program using windows command prompt. I am currently stuck and can't run the **./configure** script. Windows prompt keep telling me that it is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Although, the configure script file is already in the Mr Bayes folder.

It is called the Mr Bayes program. I have already downloaded compilers (code blocks for the gcc versions). I also tried to convert it to a .bat file but it isn't working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: configure script is Linux and not Windows.  Windows Subsystem for Linux can do this no probs but Windows doesn't interpret configure scripts like this without some help.  If you look inside of the script, you can see that it is done with bash or sh.. not cmd.exe.  I can't think of a better time to learn about WSL!  It's REALLY COOL.

Comment: How should I proceed with the installation? Is there no way for me to run the configure in windows at all?

Comment: Yes, you might be able to install CYGWIN or MINGW and run it that way.. but no.. you need some sort of Linux thingamajigger to do what you are trying to do. I would suggest that Windows Subsystem for Linux is MUCH MUCH better.  Also.. knowledge of how to use Linux (which this will give you) is golden knowledge these days.  WSL is added via "Windows Features".

Comment: BACK UP!!  You are using the Unix source code build.  Simply download the prebuilt exe for windows here.. https://github.com/NBISweden/MrBayes/releases/download/v3.2.7/MrBayes-3.2.7-WIN.zip

Comment: I would STILL learn about WSL.. cool stuff.. :)